# How would someone solve a problem such as $f(x) = -13$ in Alg 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The problem is:

> Find $f(x) = -13$ given that $f(x) = 2x - 3$.

How would someone solve this, and what does it stand for? I know how to do something such as $f(3) = 2x-3.$

Comment: What are we meant to use for $f(x)$?

Comment: Assuming the function in question is invertible, then you have $f(x)=-13\iff x=f^{-1}(-13)$

Comment: @Sloan use 2x - 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use substitution; If two things are equal, then they are interchangable.

Since $$f(x)=-13$$
and 
$$f(x)=2x-3$$
by the first statement we have that 
$$f(x)=-13=2x-3$$

Now you can simply use equality identites, or inverse properties to solve for $x$.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To find when $f(x) = -13$, all you need to do is set the function equal to $-13$ and solve for $x$.

Since the function is $2x - 3$, how would you set up the equation?